# Folder is not accessable, owner is not changeable. What should I do?

Tags: windows-7

I'm facing currently a problem with a folder in windows 7, that is not accessable. Such a problem I had treated often in the last years on several pc's. But today the problem seems harder than the last times.

In the past I get to grips with this by changing the folder owner and then modify the security settings. But this time it is not possible. If I want to set the owner, it says that I have no access for the change of owner.

I already have tried to remove the folder by using the administrator-console, but this also print access restricted.

What could I do. Do I have to start with PE and remove the folder? Are there alternatives?

Comment: What error is returned when you attempt to access the folder and/or change the security permissions?

Comment: It only have told me that the acces is not allowed. Nothing else. It was a windows error message (red). After I have done a reboot the folders were deleted. So my problem disappeard.

Comment: only administrators are allowed to change ownership to themselves. Did you do proper elevation before trying to change ownership of the folder?

Answer (score 1):

If you start in a PE environment (live CDs are available for this) - you can use a ICACLS to force an ownership change.

Also [XCACLS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825751) is renowned for being good at forcing permissions changes when normally it is not possible.

Is these fail, try a linux liveCD such as Kali which can be used to overwrite the security on a file and unlock it to "Everyone" - which leaves you free to reset your permissions afterwards.